# How to check Aria-Invalid in an Input Form

Tags: javascript, wai-aria, alerts

How can you check the value of aria-invalid in an input form?

Here's my input field and the value of aria-invalid is false:

```
<input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" id="contact-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Email *">
```

I need to identify the aria-invalid if it's true or false.
Here's my javascript for identifying this and I'm having a difficulty

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input_email = document.getElementById("contact-email");

});
```

Help with this please thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getAttribute()` to get the value of attributes, in your case `aria-invalid`

```
document.getElementById("contact-email").getAttribute("aria-invalid")
```

Comment: there's nothing special about aria attributes.  they can be queried and set just like any other html attribute, as @tushar shows.